# Windows update 20H2 makes the PC crash, could updating directly to 21H1 be a solution?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, bsod

I'm currently running Windows 10 64-bit 1909 and since a few weeks Windows has been asking me to update to version 20H2.

I once did the update, but PC crashed while updating. When switched on, it completed the update, but after a few minutes of it being on, it would crash with the BSOD saying there was an error "KMODE-EXCEPTION NOT HANDLED". I then uninstalled it, to reinstall it again hoping that it would not crash again during the update; it didn't but the error persisted. I have no idea why.

I then uninstalled again the update and, as of now, in version 1909, I have never had errors like that. I thought of updating directly to version 21H1 from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), but I don't know if that error will present itself again, because I have no idea what might cause it.

EDIT: I tried to update from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) but at the end of everything it's still version 1909.

Comment: Not an answer, but anecdotally 21H1 has worked (essentially) flawless for me on rather old hardware. That was a bare metal install to be clear. Regarding the KMODE-EXCEPTION, my understanding is that this could be a driver issue, which may or may not be affected by an OS update.

Comment: Here is more info - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x1e--kmode-exception-not-handled.

Comment: I read that it may be a driver issue, but I don't how to check if this is the case for me... I think it is definitely affected by an OS update because as soon as I installed 20H2 the BSODs started to appear, and as soon as I uninstalled it they stopped.

Comment: That a certain Windows version triggers a problem is still not a sufficient indicator to say that it is really the cause. A defect driver may have worked on older Windows versions without that you have encountered any problems if by chance the driver bug was not triggered or affected a region in the kernel that was not used. I would download the latest Windows 10 version using Media Creation Tool and install that version as upgrade.

Comment: @LorenzoB. There's usually an error code with the error message, either numerical or hexadecimal _(that error code is vital to troubleshooting)_. Was Win 10 ever clean installed or was it updated from Win 7/8 when Win 10 was initially installed? Do you have a lot of programs installed, as a clean install may be the most efficient route if it only takes a half-hour to reinstall programs _(prior to: copy each user's `%UserProfile%` to another partition or move the user data directories off `C:` (via each directory's Properties - Location tab) and copy the `*.dat` files and `AppData` directory)_